# Incorrect record in DB of decimal field of the form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to write in the database values ​​from 'last_price' = 9.12345678 (I need 8 characters after the dot)

CakePHP - last 3.6.7, PHP 7.2x64, MySQL 5.7x64, Field 'last_price' type in the database: DECIMAL 20, 8

**Controller:**

```
 public function add ()
    {
        // debug ($ this-> request-> getData ());
        $ pair = $ this-> Pairs-> newEntity ();
        if ($ this-> request-> is ('post')) {
            $ pair = $ this-> Pairs-> patchEntity ($ pair, $ this-> request-> getData ());
            // debug ($ pair);
            if ($ this-> Pairs-> save ($ pair)) {
                $ this-> Flash-> success (__ ('The pair has been saved.'));
                return $ this-> redirect (['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $ this-> Flash-> error (__ ('The pair could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $ exchanges = $ this-> Pairs-> Exchanges-> find ('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $ this-> set (compact ('pair', 'exchanges'));
    }
```

**Content $ this-> request-> getData ():**

```
[
'exchange_id' => '1',
'title' => '12121',
'last_price' => '9.12345678',
'favorites' => '0'
]
```

**PairsTable.php (model)**

```
$ validator
            -> decimal ('last_price', 8)
            // -> maxLength ('last_price', 30)
            -> requirePresence ('last_price', 'create')
            -> notEmpty ('last_price');
```

I'm click to ADD, but the following query is coming to the database:

```
2018-07-24 07:09:19 Debug: duration = 0 rows = 1 INSERT INTO pairs (exchange_id, title, last_price, favorites, created, modified) VALUES (1, '5453534534543', '9.123457', 0, '2018 -07-24 07:09:19 ',' 2018-07-24 07:09:19 ')
```

WHY 'last_price' = 9.123457 ?!!!????
I see- it is written in the database as 9.12345700

Why not 9.12345678 ??

Comment: What does the commented `debug($pair)` show? ps, when posting code, please make sure it's properly formatted, these spaces make it invalid - thanks!

Comment: This is the reason: https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/source-class-Cake.Database.Type.DecimalType.html#93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you solve this, I set up a table with decimal_value (decimal(18,12)), float_value (float(18,12)), double_value (double(18,12)).

[image: Image of retrieved data from database]

double_value was accurate on all three inserts.

Change column type to DOUBLE. Clear the orm_cache.

Comment: This is not an overly good suggestion, even if it works in this very specific case the OP is having. DOUBLEs are floating points too, ie approximations, and thus are subject to rounding errors and platform specific implementations! Just because they have a higher precision than "regular FLOATs", they should still not be used for storing data that requires exact values!

Comment: Right @ndm . In anyway floating points seems never to be 100% accurate. Thought about an approach to store decimal number as integer? Say we want 18, 12, and we want to store 1340.12. That would make an integer value like 1340120000000000. RWNType (RealWorldNumberType). Some way specify the point position for the property. Probably bad for performance.